# php shell_exec() out put to get a text file

Tags: php, command-line, exec, shell-exec

I'm trying to run `rate -c 192.168.122.0/24` command on my Centos computer and write down the output of that command to the text file using `shell_exec('rate -c 192.168.122.0/24')` command; still no luck!!

Comment: Are you sure the `rate` command exists. Does it work on the commandline?

Comment: Could you tell us what you get in the terminal after running the command ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you forgot to mention, your command provides a **non ending output stream**. To read the output in real time, you need to use [**popen**](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.popen.php).

Example from PHP's website :

```
$handle = popen('/path/to/executable 2>&1', 'r');
echo "'$handle'; " . gettype($handle) . "\n";
$read = fread($handle, 2096);
echo $read;
pclose($handle);
```

You can read the process output just like a file.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need PHP, you can just run that in the shell :

```
rate -c 192.168.122.0/24 > file.txt
```

If you have to run it from PHP :

```
shell_exec('rate -c 192.168.122.0/24 > file.txt');
```

The ">" character redirect the output of the command to a file.

Comment: Well if you run the command yourself do you get an output ? With and without the "> file.txt". This is weird if the text file is empty, that means that the command doesn't print any result.

Comment: thank you for your reply .yes i can get the out put when run the command in terminal its non ending output stream

Comment: @Roshan: Did you run into a "permission problem"? Try adding `2>&1` to the above mentioned command line. I doubt if you can run arbitrary commands from php.

Comment: @Salman There is no problem in file permission i can get the out out of ls -l to the text file easily..

Comment: @Roshan: it could still be a permission problem, ls command could have different permissions compared to rate command. Did you try redirecting standard error to a text file?

Comment: Ok if this is a non ending output that is normal. I'll try another answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can also get the output via PHP, and then save it to a text file

```
    $output = shell_exec('rate -c 192.168.122.0/24');
    $fh = fopen('output.txt','w');
    fwrite($fh,$output);
    fclose($fh);
```

Comment: No luck buddy nothing get write to the text file

Answer (score 0):

```
$path_to_file = 'path/to/your/file';
$write_command = 'rate -c 192.168.122.0/24 >> '.$path_to_file;
shell_exec($write_command);
```

hopes this helps. :D
And this will direct you to a good way. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/127529/41966